# Event retention in Microsoft Azure EventHub

Tags: azure, amazon-kinesis, azure-eventhub

I was checking on details about message retention in event hub.
Suppose, I have set the retentionPolicy as 1 day and I had send some messages. Then, if I change the message retentionPolicy to 3 days, will the existing `eventData` also be retained for 3 days?

Answer (score 3):

[Absolutely Yes.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/servicebus/archive/2015/03/09/data-retention-in-event-hubs.aspx)

And one more important detail about retention policy - EventHubs **does not apply the retention policy at message level**. Its at file-system level. EventHubs is a high-throughput event ingestion pipeline. In-short it's a stream of events on cloud - to provide higher thruput & performance - we don't deal with any event-level operations (for example, an equivalent offering is ServiceBus Q/Topics - TimeToLive property on Message).  Behind the covers - eventhubs actually stores data in `pages` (of lets say, for explanation sake 10 MB). Retention policy will be applied only on these `pages`. So - some of your messages which were sent 10 days before might also still be present, even if you have a retention policy of 1 day - if you have very-very-low data rates on the hub - making into that `page`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, If you use UpdateEventHubAsync to update the message retention period. However, the actual message cleanup time is not guaranteed. The azure infrastructure may decide to cleanup based on its dynamics.

Comment: Do you have a link to the documentation that says that the existing messages will also be affected with the update? I am aware that I can update the eventhub retention days using the UpdateEventHubAsync method.