# retention time of eventhub

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-eventhub

I read [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/servicebus/archive/2015/03/09/data-retention-in-event-hubs.aspx) but I am still a bit confused about retention time in EventHub. Does it work like a sliding window? In other words, if the retention window is 1 day, does it only guarantee for the events to be retained for the lats 24 hours given the current UTC time? Or will the EventHub potentially be flushed at midnight every day? I understand that the EventHub may also contain events older than one day. Any feedback would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, It is a **Sliding window** & EventHub guaratee's that the events are retained for the last 24 hours (which is configurable).

Older events before the Window will be present too - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33577042/3277385)'s why.

[Here,](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/servicebus/archive/2015/03/09/data-retention-in-event-hubs.aspx)'s a nice blog from our Program Mgr about retention policy of EventHubs.

HTH!
Sree